# Background-image on body - image have zoom in it

Tags: html, css, background-image

I would like to place a background image on the body element to be stretch on the entire browser screen.

The problem is that while doing this the image getting some "zoom in" and image is cutting due to this.

For example let take this current image:

http://www.baltana.com/files/wallpapers-15/Pug-Dog-HD-Wallpapers-38933.jpg

And see how its zoom the image and cuts some parts around.

I've tried to play with the CSS background cover features but with no luck.

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xThY.jpg');
  background-size: cover, 100%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: If the image is set to cover the entire window and the  window is open to different proportions than the image, the image will be cropped in some way. What is the specific result you're going for?

Comment: Have a look at how the background-size property is meant to work. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might work

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <title>This is a test page</title>
            <style>
                body {
                background-image: url('http://www.baltana.com/files/wallpapers-15/Pug-Dog-HD-Wallpapers-38933.jpg');
                background-size: 100%;
                backgroun-reapeat:no-repeat
                }

            </style>
        </head>
        <body>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xThY.jpg');
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

probably this what u looking for ! but this  will change image aspect ratio!

Answer (score 0):

did you mean something like this?

```
html{
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://www.baltana.com/files/wallpapers-15/Pug-Dog-HD-Wallpapers-38933.jpg');
    background-size:  contain;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

i didnt put it in a snippet because the code doesnt work in it. i tried it in chrome, firefox, edge and even internet explorer and it seems to work fine. hope this helps.